# Is it possible for an after_create trigger to fire but the create that triggered it to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm in an interesting situation where I have this transaction

```
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        Foo.create!(user)
        Bar.create(user)
      end
```

I see the after_create trigger on Foo was run (a separate row was saved to a different table, say Bazz). I also see Bar was created but I don't see a row for Foo being created which is stumping me.

Is this possible in rails or is the only explanation that someone went into the database and deleted the Foo row?

Answer (score 0):

`after_create` and `after_save` hooks are wrapped in a transaction with the save so if an exception happens in the `after_create` then the whole chain will be rolled back.  You can avoid this by using `after_commit, on: :create` to run the callback when the database transaction involving Foo is completed and it has finally saved in the database.

Comment: The problem I ran into was that after_create succeeded but I do not see evidence that the original create succeeded. Is there a quirk with Rails where this is possible? Or is the only explanation for this that someone went into to delete the row (Foo) afterwards?

Comment: @irregular This is not possible as after create won't run if the original create didn't succeed. Only explanation is that someone interfered with it or maybe it got updated and you haven't yet found it in DB or something like that. This could have been possible if we were talking about a before_create callback.